# z-index chrome bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

I'm experiencing a really annoying bug that seems to only happen on Windows and OS X: the z-index of an element whose parent has fixed position doesn't work on Chrome! I converted my odd situation to a simple code:

html:

```
<div id="mask">
    &nbsp;
</div>

<div id="box">
    <div class="below-mask circle">
        should be below the mask
    </div>

    <div class="above-mask circle">
        should be above the mask
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#box {
    position: fixed;
}

#mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9998;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.75);
    border-radius: 75px;
    line-height: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.above-mask {
    z-index: 9999;
}

.below-mask {
    z-index: 9997;
}​
```

sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/gibatronic/umbgp/

I tested on Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 15, Opera 12.02 and Safari 5.1.7 on OS X and Windows and all of them displayed as expected.
I also tested on Ubuntu 12.10 and it worked just fine for every browser including Chrome!
I even tested on Kindle 4 browser and it worked!

I wonder if anyone knows any kind of fix to workaround this issue!

Comment: actually, on ff 16.0.1 it does not display as expected as well...

Comment: @LorDex in which OS did you tested? Everything is working fine for me on Ubuntu and Windows with Firefox 16.0.1!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

one800higgins's answer is along the right lines.  The real answer is that [on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, `position: fixed` always creates a new stacking context, even when `z-index` is `auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).  So the stacking context hierarchy looks like this:

- document root (z-index `0`)

  - `#mask` (z-index `9998`)
  - `#box` (z-index `0`)

    - `.above-mask` (z-index `9999`)
    - `.below-mask` (z-index `9997`)

That means that `9998` is never compared with `9999` or `9997` to determine stacking order.  Instead, `9999` is compared with `9997` to determine which of `.above-mask` and `.below-mask` is further in front, and then once everything inside `#box` is stacked in that context, it's treated as a single layer at z-index `0` which gets stacked behind `#mask` at z-index `9998`.

This also explains why @TheNextBillGates's answer of moving `#mask` inside `#box` works - because then `#mask` is in the same stacking context as `.above-mask` and `.below-mask`.  I highly recommend the above link for more comprehensive details, and you should also see [the announcement for the stacking change for `fixed` elements in Chrome](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements).

Comment: Very good explanation and thanks for the link. This is not a bug as I've always thought it was ! You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this bug, and its still happening in Google Chrome v26. I could set the z-index as high as I wanted to from code or Chrome's CSS editor and it made no difference (and the element's position was set to absolute).  The same z-index setting was working as expected in Firefox and even IE8-IE10.   When I switched the parent element from position:fixed to position:absolute then the child element's z-index worked fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `#mask` inside of the `#box` it works just fine.

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="below-mask circle">should be below the mask</div>
    <div class="above-mask circle">should be above the mask</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheNextBillGates/jKm4b/

Not sure why this is just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a z-index to your fixed div.  That should cause chrome to respect the z-index values for all it's children as well.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple z-index stacks is unfortunate and confusing in my opinion, however you may be able to solve this without changing your html structure if you raise the z-index of any of the target element's parents.  Try to find a parent element that is a sibling of the troublesome element overlapping your content.  Apply this styling:

```
position: relative; z-index: [# higher than overlapping element's z-index];
```

Your milage may vary depending on your project, however this solution worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because its not at the bottom of the page like modal windows are suppose to be. Easy fix is to just grab all of the modal windows and throw them into a div before the ending body tag. Example below fixes every chrome issue i have.

```
$('body').append('<div id="modelContainer" />');
$('.modal').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#modelContainer');
})
```

Comment: that would be a workaround, not really nice to have to recover to js to solve it, I was more interested in a solution for the z-index stack problem, but as the accepted answer points out, it was wrong what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Change or remove the `position: fixed` on `#box`, and you're set.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/one800higgins/umbgp/18/)

Comment: unfortunately does, because the ```#box``` div in my project is actually a sticky menu, that's why it has fixed position, and the idea of all this is to highlight an item from the menu in a guided tour.

Comment: removing 'position:fixed' wont do any good, because mask div is semi-transparent.

Comment: Check the jsFiddle I posted... Removing `position: fixed` is all I did and it worked perfectly. Transparency has nothing to do with it... You can set them to solid colors and see for yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry @one800higgins but it doesn't make any sense, if I set ```#box``` to be position ```relative``` or ```absolute``` it works just fine, why only ```fixed``` is cursed like that?

Comment: @gibatronic I'm trying to figure that out too. I would think that it would behave the same between fixed and absolute elements, but for some reason making it a fixed element causes this behavior.