# Why you see the header of my website in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, header

I have a header with these properties:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-size: 20px;
width:100%;
height: 45px;
z-index:100000000000000000;
```

http://regaderamay.es.vu/cumpled

In all browsers it looks good, but in chrome only looks a header height 1px. I think it has to do with the slider images of wallpaper. But do not know how to fix it. Any help?

In Chrome for mac: 
[image]
I highlighted in red is what is left of the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jaumesv, I think this has to do with the [z-index Chrome bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019155/z-index-chrome-bug). As far as I can tell, the bug has not been fixed. You might want to try to use **position: absolute** instead of **position: fixed**, although I tried that out in web inspector and had no luck.